# 'ComputeShader does not contain a definition for SetMatrix'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compute-shader

Currently I am trying to follow [this tutorial on ray tracing using compute shaders](http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/2014/06/27/Compute-Shaders-Are-Nifty.html). I am trying to set the matrices for the compute shader using `ComputeShader.SetMatrix(string name, Matrix4x4 val)`, or in my case specifically, `RayTracingShader.SetMatrix("_CameraToWorld", _camera.cameraToWorldMatrix);`.

However, I get the error `'ComputeShader does not contain a definition for SetMatrix'`, even though [this Unity page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ComputeShader.SetMatrix.html) clearly indicates that it should be possible. I am also unable to find anyone on Google with similar problems. I have just now updated Unity to version 5.5.4p4 Personal. Before that it didn't work either.

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unity 5.5 does not define `ComputeShader.SetMatrix`.](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/ComputeShader.html)

You need to update to a version of Unity where `ComputeShader.SetMatrix` exists.

It seems like it first arrived in [2017.3](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/ComputeShader.SetMatrix.html)

Comment: How would I instead accomplish this in the latest version of Unity? Downgrading doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: @Jack I don't understand your question. It [still exists in the latest non-alpha version, 2019.3](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/ComputeShader.SetMatrix.html)

Comment: @Jack also, in the question, you stated that you're using 5.5.4p4, a version that came out [in August 2017](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases/5.5.4p4). This answer recommends updating to at least 2017.3, a version that came out [in December 2017](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/12/19/unity-2017-3-is-here/). Can you explain what you mean by "Downgrading"?

Comment: I worked under the assumption that I had installed the latest version, which most people I think would expect if they had just updated through the "Check for updates" function. I see now that it isn't the latest version, which is seriously stupid imo

Comment: @Jack checking for updates in unity won't update the major version. This is pretty standard for development software to help avoid breaking things. Visual studio is the same way, for example. [Also, please see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).

Comment: I would avoid using that link.